# Ive got a problem with updating my ComboBox, as soon as I recall the fill ComboBox I get all duplicates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

Im trying to update my ComboBox as soon as ive made a new Capture file with data in it. If I close the form and reopen it, its obviously updated but that seems like a cheap way to program it. (To quickly close the form and open a new one) So far when i recall the method to refill the ComboBox it seems to include existing data and hardcopies everything.

My code as for now:

As soon as the form load this is executed:

```
    private void FormCapSave_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\pc\Documents\textfolder");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.cap");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            if (!comboBoxSaveCap.Items.Contains(file))
            {
                comboBoxSaveCap.Items.Add(file.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Followed by the button to add a new Cap file:

```
    private void buttonFormSaveAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.AfterNamingCapFile();
        if (Program.MainForm.boolSave == false)
        {
            labelFormSaveException.ForeColor = Color.Tomato;
            labelFormSaveException.Text = "Cap exists";
        }
        else
        {
            labelFormSaveException.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            labelFormSaveException.Text = "Cap file added";
            ResetForm();
        }
    }
```

My ResetForm(); is basically a copy from the first on load method:

```
    private void ResetForm()
    {
        DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\pc\Documents\textfolder");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.cap");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            if (!comboBoxSaveCap.Items.Contains(file))
            {
                comboBoxSaveCap.Items.Add(file.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the contents of your combobox before re-populating it.

```
    private void ResetForm()
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new 
        DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\pc\Documents\textfolder");
        FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.cap");
        comboBoxSaveCap.Items.Clear(); // Missing this bit
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            if (!comboBoxSaveCap.Items.Contains(file))
            {
                comboBoxSaveCap.Items.Add(file.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate works like a charm, feel kinda dumb that I didn't think of that before

Comment: @T.Janson if this answer worked for you then please consider marking this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the Items collection, but you can also remove the whole loop required to add items one by one if you use the DataSource property. This has the side advantage to allow you to get back a full FileInfo when you look at the SelectedItem property

```
private void ResetForm()
{
    string path = @"C:\Users\pc\Documents\textfolder";
    comboBoxSaveCap.DataSource = null; // Clear the previous content
    comboBoxSaveCap.DataSource = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.cap");
}

void comboBoxSaveCap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = comboBoxSaveCap.SelectedItem as FileInfo;
    if(f != null)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(f.FullName);
    }
}
```